# KB2919355 updated not offered

Tags: windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

On my Windows 8.1 machines, the so-called "April Update" from KB2919355 was installed automatically by Windows Update, as expected.  However, on my 2012 R2 server, the update was not automatically installed, and Windows Update says "no updates are available".

I know that I can download and apply KB2919355 from the Microsoft Downloads center, but missing this update makes me worried that this machine may be missing other updates as well.  The server is updating directly from Microsoft, not from WSUS, and there is nothing else that I know of which could be blocking the update.  The machine does have the prerequisite update from KB2919442.

How can I find out why this update is missing?  What can I do to make sure this doesn't continue to be an issue with other updates?

(I wish I had access to another 2012 R2 server to confirm whether this is an issue specific to this machine or not, but my other Windows servers are running 2008 R2 or 2012 original, so this update doesn't apply to them.)

Comment: Is it activated?

Comment: @MichelZ Yes.  Note that I have not had this problem before, and the machine had dozens of successful updates since January.  Also, after I gave in and manually installed the update, other new updates did show up.

Comment: For windows server 2012, you cannot even download the update. The only offerings are Win 8.1

Answer (score 1):

I've done over ten Server 2012 R2 installs, and every one has to have the KB2919442 patch, then the clearcompressionflag done before it picks up anything but the current month's patches. Once you run those and KB2919355, you'll get ~75 additional patches magically showing up from Windows Update, almost none of which have anything to do with .NET.

Comment: What is the 'clearcompressionflag'? Answers should be written to stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting Windows update.

1. `net stop wuauserv`
2. delete c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution
3. `net start wuauserv`
4. scan for updates again

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't help.  In the end, I manually applied the update.

Answer (score -3):

Install KB2919442 (no reboot) then 2919355 will detect.

Comment: The question is about a computer that already has 2919442.